# Running Java in Chrome

Tags: java, swing, google-chrome

I have a personal website in which I have a list of projects. One of these projects is a Java Swing application.

I thought it'd be cool to embed the project on the website so visitors could see it operate live. However Chrome has now completely removed support for the traditional manner of running Java.

Something along the lines of [Live Connect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/LiveConnect) would be acceptable, but it seems to be outdated.

Basically, I'd like to know if there's any way (current or planned) to run Java in Chrome, or if my best bet is providing a link to the jar file for download. Or should I go ahead with embedding it the [traditional way](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html) and let Chrome users go by the wayside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing java applets and java web start. Chrome has removed support for java applets. For a swing application, you've linked as "the traditional way" to use Java Web Start, which runs java applications *outside of browsers*. This should continue to work in Chrome just fine:

> Chrome no longer supports NPAPI (technology required for Java applets)
>
> The Java plug-in for web browsers relies on the cross platform plugin
>   architecture NPAPI, which has been supported by all major web browsers
>   for over a decade. Google's Chrome version 45 (scheduled for release
>   in September 2015) drops support for NPAPI, impacting plugins for
>   Silverlight, Java, Facebook Video and other similar NPAPI based
>   plugins.
>
> Java applications are offered though web browsers as either a web
>   start application (which do not interact with the browser once they
>   are launched) or as a Java applet (which might interact with the
>   browser). This change does not affect Web Start applications, it only
>   impacts applets.

([source](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml))

Comment: Ah, I was a bit confused. However due to the difficulty of getting a self-signed jar to run using Java Web Start, I think the best option is still hosting the jar file itself for download...

Comment: signing is only needed if your jar needs rights beyond the sandbox. However, if it does, I agree that it might be more work than just hosting the file for download.

Comment: That hasn't been my experience, specifying sandboxed permissions still leads to it being rejected by Java when signed by an unverified publisher.

Comment: Ah, indeed [I got it wrong](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias), you'll need signing even with sandboxed ones, and there must be a trusted source.

Comment: And obtaining a certificate from a trusted source requires payment, though sometimes for open source you can get one for free, but this usually requires you send them an ID. Neither of these options are convenient for simply trying to show off a personal project over the internet.